# Error: "A field or property with the name was not found on the selected data source" get only on server

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, iis-7.5, sql-server-2012

I publish my project without any warning on local iis and it works correctly (localhost/[myprojectName]). so, i upload them to server with cute ftp. but in server i get this error apear for all my filed like [tableName].[filedName]:

> A field or property with the name **'ConfirmStatuse.Name'** was not found
>   on the selected data source

here's my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="ordergv" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SummaryOfOrderSrc" AllowSorting="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField SelectText="select" ShowSelectButton="True" ButtonType="Button"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderId"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ConfirmStatuse.Name"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderStatuse.Name"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PaymentStatuse.Name"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ShipmentStatuse.Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField >
            <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="CreatedDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# GetPersianDate( Eval("CreatedDate")) %>' /></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:LinqDataSource ID="SummaryOfOrderSrc" runat="server" ContextTypeName="Ahooratech.DAL.DataClasses1DataContext" EntityTypeName="" OrderBy="CreatedDate desc" TableName="Orders">
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

I check the size of my project in local iis and on server. both of them are same(8,459,009 bytes)

so it means i use same database and same files for run my application for run on local and server. so why i get this error only in server?

The only difference here is on version of iis, i think my server iis version is 7.0. but is it important for i get this error?!!! i don't think so. i'm really confused.

(My local project and server project use same connection string).

EDIT: I publish project on another host and it works! but it doesn't work on my original server yet.

Comment: Resulting LINQ query object doesn't have the property given. What exactly is not clear for you? Error message is pretty straight forward.

Comment: hi dear, I have that property in my result query. error message is pretty clear but why it work on local but not work on server. I check the all things. all thing are same. @abatishchev

Comment: Okay, I see. Hmm. Maybe you have a silly but hidden mistake in deployment: are you sure you've copied the app properly and assemblies weren't cached? Double check. And try to delete Temp ASP.NET Files folder.

Comment: yes. i also delete all of them files and publish them. they are exactly same is size, even in bytes 8,459,009 bytes. i'm really confused @abatishchev . what thing can i ask or search for this error ?!

Comment: @abatishchev is the ver of iis important here?

Comment: @abatishchev i add EDIT para at the end of my post

Comment: @abatishchev i found this strange problem. tnx

Comment: @abatishchev i was bought a host with iis6 and cant refund it. i must migrate 7.5 to 6. do you have a good link for this?

Comment: I too am having this issue. I have complete control over both my local and the web server environments and have assured that code/database are all identical. This definitely seems to be a version issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the IIS Version on my server is 6. but my local is 7.5. 
I publish my project on another server with iis 7.5 and it works

**Solution1**: I create a summaryOfOrder like this:

```
class summaryOfOrder
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public string ConfirmStatusName { get; set; }
        public string OrderStatusName { get; set; }
        public string PaymentStatusName { get; set; }
        public string ShippingStatusName { get; set; }
        public string CreatedDate { get; set; }


    }
```

and change

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ConfirmStatuse.Name"  />
```

to

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ConfirmStatusName"  />
```

and bind class to grid by

```
gv.datasource = mySummryOfOrder; 
gv.databind();
```

and initialize a list of this type and bind it to grid programmatically

**Update solution 2** convert

> asp:BoundField

to

> asp:TemplateField 
>   and using

```
<%# Eval("Worker.FullName")%>
```

Comment: That got it working after trying for long time ! But don't know why issue was occurring after deployed on different server, it was working correctly with boundfield on my local. Is it because I have .NET 4.5 on my machine which has EF 6 where as deployment server had .NET 4 and probably with EF6 ?

Comment: I'm not sure but think it's because of IIS.@AltafPatel

Comment: Both machines had IIS 6.1, except later had SP2. @Mohammadreza

Answer (score 5):

This is the same issue to the one described here - [Binding to Navigation Property causes " A field or property with the name 'X.X' was not found on the selected data source" in IIS 6 ONLY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19050993/3020983)

It appears to be an issue with the BoundField control element.  As suggested in [an answer provided by user Anant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19548049/3020983) in the article linked above, you can convert the BoundField to a TemplateField and it will work (using "OrderStatuse.Name" in your example).  That solution worked for me.

Although this really doesn't explain ***why*** IIS6 can't support the BoundField in this way.

*Mind boggling.*

Answer (score 2):

I have sorted out with adding those bound fields in the selected query.

Error message:

> A field or property with the name 'tax_percentage' was not found on the selected data source

Solution:

I didn't select the tax_percentage in the select query so the above error message came. Just select the `tax_percentage` in my query.

Answer (score 2):

If your datasource is a list of objects, certify that the properties of your class are definied as public, like this:

```
class YourClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

opposite to:

```
class YourClass
{
    private int Id { get; set; }
    private string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

Regards