# Binding to Navigation Property causes " A field or property with the name 'X.X' was not found on the selected data source" in IIS 6 ONLY

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, iis, gridview, data-binding

I see that similar questions have been asked, but I don't think any of them specifically address the environmental difference that I'm seeing. I have an ASP.NET Web Forms application that contains a `GridView`, which I am manually binding to a collection of Entity Framework entities. I am using a `BoundField` that references a navigation property on one of my entities.

Previous posts indicate that this isn't supported, but the entire solution works perfectly in IIS 7.5 running on Windows 7. However, when the application is deployed to the web server running IIS 6 on Windows Server 2003 R2, it fails with the `HttpException`:

> "A field or property with the name 'Worker.FullName' was not found on
>   the selected data source."

Here is a relevant summary of the code:

**Entities:**

```
public class WorkerAssignment
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid WorkerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Worker Worker { get; set; }
}

public class Worker
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:GridView 
    ID="gvWorkers" 
    runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="Id"
>
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField 
            DataField="Worker.FullName" 
            SortExpression="Worker.FullName" 
            HeaderText="Worker Name" 
        />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Both servers are running .NET Framework 4.0.30319. **What is the difference between IIS 7.5 and IIS 6 that is causing the code to function properly in the former environment and fail in the latter?**

Answer (score 11):

I'm also facing the same problem. The code similar to `DataField="Worker.FullName"` was working fine but suddenly started throwing error on DEV but not on `localhost`. I was unable to point exact issue.

The only work around solved my problem was to replace `asp:BoundField` to `asp:TemplateField` using `<%# Eval("Worker.FullName")%>`

Comment: thank you very much man, I also happened to me, works well on localhost but not on the server, use your tip and work =D

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue with IIS 7.0. Two servers running the exact same IIS version, same application pool version (4) and with the same copy of the code, but one failing and the other one working fine.

After further investigating the problem, I noticed that System.Environment.Version was returning different versions, close but different.

This is a quick test you can run to verify the version in ASP.NET:

`ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + System.Environment.Version + "');", true);`

According to my research, version 4.0.30319.1026 is affected by the bug while version 4.0.30319.34209 works fine. The first one seems to be part of .NET 4.0 while the last one seems to be part of 4.5.

The issue was resolved after upgrading the server running .NET 4.0 to 4.5.